# Resetting/Clearing a form with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to clear the form after a submission via button click. The 'clear form' jQuery works in another project I tested but for some reason it wont work here. Both the `.validateEngine` and `.LocalStorage.save` functions fire and work properly. Any insight would be appreciated.

```
function clicked (e) 
{
  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to submit?')) 
    {
       if ($("#formID").validationEngine('validate'))
       {
           my.LocalStorage.save();

        //clear form
            var $form = $("#form");
            $form.find('input:text, input:password, input:file, select, textarea').val('');
            $form.find('input:radio, input:checkbox')
            .removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');

   }
}   
e.preventDefault();  
}
```

html

```
<form id="formID" name="myForm">    

 <input class="validate[required]" type="text" id="agree" name="agree"/>         
 <button type="submit" value="Save" id="Save" onclick="clicked(event);">Submit Survey</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the form ID wrong. Change:

```
var $form = $("#form");
```

to:

```
var $form = $("#formID");
```

Also, to save selecting the same form twice it would make sense to move that variable declaration to be the first line inside the `if(confirm(...){`, like this:

```
function clicked (e) {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to submit?')) {
        var $form = $("#formID");                
        if ($form.validationEngine('validate')) {
            my.LocalStorage.save();    
            //clear form
            $form.find('input:text, input:password, input:file, select, textarea').val('');
            $form.find('input:radio, input:checkbox')
                 .removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');
        }
    }   
    e.preventDefault();  
}
```

Comment: haha after staring at it for so long I forgot I had to change my form id earlier. thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I exactly understand the structure your suggesting. If i had multiple textboxes and some were not required, would that erase what has been filled in if validate doesn't return true?

Comment: I didn't mean to be unclear - I've edited my answer to show you exactly what I mean about moving the `var $form` declaration.

Comment: Oh ok, it unfortunately doesn't work for me using this structure however it also does not duplicate submissions so I think I'm OK.

Answer (score 0):

call `$("#formID").reset();`
This is standard call in jquery to reset form.

Comment: This seemed to just refresh the page when trying.